# Ignore projection limits when setting the extent

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

Is there a way to set the extent of the figure beyond the projection limits?

For example, when using the "Rijksdriehoek" projection (EPSG 28992), the limits from Cartopy (proj4?) are wrong, way too narrow.

That projection is designed cover all of the Netherlands, but the imposed limits even cause part of the country to be cut off. Whereas I would rather set the extent slightly wider then the official boundaries to provide some extra context.

[image: Rd example]

Unfortunately, the `set_extent` method gives an error:

```
ValueError: Failed to determine the required bounds in projection 
coordinates. Check that the values provided are within the valid range 
(x_limits=[646.3608848793374, 284347.25011780026], 
y_limits=[308289.55751689477, 637111.0245778429]).
```

The `set_xlim`/`set_ylim` methods don't seem to do anything, which would work for a normal matplotlib axes.

Example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature

projection = ccrs.epsg(28992)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,10), subplot_kw=dict(projection=projection))

ax.coastlines(resolution='10m')
ax.add_feature(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('cultural', 'admin_0_boundary_lines_land', '10m', facecolor='none', edgecolor='k'))
```

The extent of the figure is automatically set to the limits of the projection:

```
print(projection.bounds)
print(ax.get_extent())

(646.3608848793374, 284347.25011780026, 308289.55751689477, 637111.0245778429)
(646.3608848793374, 284347.25011780026, 308289.55751689477, 637111.0245778429)
```

According to the documentation about the projection, the actual limits should be: `(-700 300000 289000 629000)`. But even those seem a bit strict for visualization purposes.

See for example the "Scope of validity section" at:

https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=nl&u=https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijksdriehoeksco%25C3%25B6rdinaten

Comment: Stupid question: On the scale this limitation occurs (i.e. a map of the whole country), would you observe any difference to any other projection that does not have those limitations?

Comment: Yes that would be possible of course, using `UTM 31N` for example. But it would require reprojecting the raster data I have as well, which is less optimal. It's a workaround though.

Comment: Again, I might be wrong here, but had in mind that the difference between coordinate systems would be some 100 meters at most, so a reprojection might not even be necessary? (That is based on Gauß-Krüger vs. UMT in Germany, I don't know about "Rijksdriehoek")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by @`pp-mo` is excellent. However, here is an alternative solution. The working code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature

# subclassing for a modified projection
class nd_prj(ccrs.Stereographic):
    """
    Hacked projection for ccrs.epsg(28992) to get extended plotting limits
    """
    def __init__(self):
        globe = ccrs.Globe(ellipse=u'bessel')
        super(nd_prj, self).__init__(central_latitude=52.15616055555555, \
                     central_longitude=5.38763888888889, \
                     #true_scale_latitude=52.0, \
                     scale_factor=0.9999079, \
                     false_easting=155000, false_northing=463000, globe=globe)

    @property
    def x_limits(self):
        return (500, 300000)   # define the values you need

    @property
    def y_limits(self):
        return (300000, 650000) # define the values you need

projection = nd_prj()  # make use of the projection
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,10), subplot_kw=dict(projection=projection))

ax.coastlines(resolution='10m')
ax.add_feature(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('cultural', 'admin_0_boundary_lines_land', \
                                            '10m', facecolor='none', edgecolor='k'))
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot:

[image]

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Thanks! After some digging on Github I also came to the conclusion that a custom projection is probably the best way deal with this. See my answer below for a slight variation on this. Initializing the projection with `ccrs.epsg(28992)` is fine in this case, since the definition itself is correct, just the limits aren't.

Answer (score 4):

The answer of @Rutger_Kassies is excellent but with the latest version of Cartopy and PyProj that solution has some issues, I have fixed and simplified it:

```py
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.crs import Projection
from pyproj import CRS

class ProjectCustomExtent(Projection):
    def __init__(self, epsg, extent):
        self.xmin, self.xmax, self.ymin, self.ymax = extent
        super().__init__(CRS.from_epsg(epsg).to_string())

    @Projection.boundary.getter
    def boundary(self):
        coords = ((self.x_limits[0], self.y_limits[0]),
                  (self.x_limits[0], self.y_limits[1]),
                  (self.x_limits[1], self.y_limits[1]),
                  (self.x_limits[1], self.y_limits[0]))
        return ccrs.sgeom.LineString(coords)

    @Projection.x_limits.getter
    def x_limits(self):
        return self.xmin, self.xmax

    @Projection.y_limits.getter
    def y_limits(self):
        return self.ymin, self.ymax

# example
projection = ProjectCustomExtent(epsg=3005, extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
```

Answer (score 3):

I found that the projection limits in Cartopy are taken from those in Proj4, so there isn't an immediate fix.
However, you can define an equivalent projection by interrogating the parameters ...
Firstly,

```
>>> import pyepsg
>>> proj4_epsg = pyepsg.get(28992)
>>> print(proj4_epsg.as_proj4())
'+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.417,50.3319,465.552,-0.398957,0.343988,-1.8774,4.0725 +units=m +no_defs'
>>>
```

Then, for example ..

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeat
proj_equivalent = ccrs.Stereographic(central_longitude=5.3876388888, central_latitude=52.15616055555,
    false_easting=155000, false_northing=463000, scale_factor=0.9999079)
ax = plt.axes(projection=proj_equivalent)
x0, x1 = -4.7e4, +3.7e5
y0, y1 = 2.6e5, 6.82e5
ax.set_extent((x0, x1, y0, y1), crs=proj_equivalent)
ax.coastlines('50m', color='blue'); ax.gridlines()
ax.add_feature(cfeat.BORDERS, edgecolor='red', linestyle='--')
plt.show()
```

Which yields a plot like this :
[image]

Clearly, the built-in county boundaries are very crude here.
Also, I haven't set up the correct ellipse, which requires a little more research.
But it shows how to break through the limitation of the provided projection boundaries.

I don't know if there is an opportunity here to push back against Proj4 ?

Answer (score 2):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
```

Here is a slightly more flexible version of a "custom extent" projection class. This should also make it work for other projections. For example in the case of a UTM projection for a country spanning the equator. The extent still has to be entered manually, it could be extended to expand the default `proj4` extent by a percentage.

```
class ProjectCustomExtent(ccrs.Projection):

    def __init__(self, epsg=28992, extent=[-200000, 500000, 200000, 700000]):

        xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = extent

        self.xmin = xmin
        self.xmax = xmax
        self.ymin = ymin
        self.ymax = ymax

        super().__init__(ccrs.epsg(epsg).proj4_params)

    @property
    def boundary(self):

        coords = ((self.x_limits[0], self.y_limits[0]),
                  (self.x_limits[0], self.y_limits[1]),
                  (self.x_limits[1], self.y_limits[1]),
                  (self.x_limits[1], self.y_limits[0]))

        return ccrs.sgeom.LineString(coords)

    @property
    def bounds(self):
        xlim = self.x_limits
        ylim = self.y_limits
        return xlim[0], xlim[1], ylim[0], ylim[1]

    @property
    def threshold(self):
        return 1e5

    @property
    def x_limits(self):
        return self.xmin, self.xmax

    @property
    def y_limits(self):
        return self.ymin, self.ymax
```

Get a new projection:

```
projection = ProjectCustomExtent(epsg=28992, extent=[-300000, 500000, -100000, 800000])
```

The result:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,15), subplot_kw=dict(projection=projection), facecolor='w')

ax.coastlines(resolution='10m')
ax.add_feature(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('cultural', 'admin_0_boundary_lines_land', '10m', 
                                            facecolor='none', edgecolor='k'), label='Stereo', zorder=999, lw=1, linestyle='-')


ax.set_extent([-100000, 400000, 200000, 700000], crs=projection)
```

[image]